# Maintenance for the Amazon RDS API in the AP-NORTHEAST-1 Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My 3 RDS instances are running in AP-NORTHEAST-1 Region. Among these, one is multi-AZ enabled and remaining two are not multi-AZ.

During the upcoming maintenance, my two non multiAZ RDS instance will have downtime for sure as it will be in one availability zone only. As per the multiAZ concept, one stand by copy of DB will be in another availability zone. I assume, region wise maintenance will be AZ by AZ, so it will not have downtime. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Maintaining a DB Instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html):

> Running a DB instance as a Multi-AZ deployment can further reduce the impact of a maintenance event, because Amazon RDS applies operating system updates by following these steps:
>
> 1. Perform maintenance on the standby.
> 2. Promote the standby to primary.
> 3. Perform maintenance on the old primary, which becomes the new standby.

Therefore, there is little or no impact to availability.